how to add complex 'view actions' when clauses?
I'm following this tree-view example: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/tree-view-sample/USAGE.md
"contributes": {
"commands": [
    {
        "command": "nodeDependencies.refreshEntry",
        "title": "Refresh",
        "icon": {
            "light": "resources/light/refresh.svg",
            "dark": "resources/dark/refresh.svg"
        }
    }
],
"menus": {
    "view/title": [
        {
            "command": "nodeDependencies.refreshEntry",
            "when": "view == nodeDependencies",
            "group": "navigation"
        }
    ]
}

}
I would like to add an extra condition to the when clause (when": "view == nodeDependencies"). For example, only show the fresh button if the file is a file with name ending in ".xs.ts". I'm using resourceFilename and regex pattern to set such condition:
"contributes": {
"commands": [
    {
        "command": "nodeDependencies.refreshEntry",
        "title": "Refresh",
        "icon": {
            "light": "resources/light/refresh.svg",
            "dark": "resources/dark/refresh.svg"
        }
    }
],
"menus": {
    "view/title": [
        {
            "command": "nodeDependencies.refreshEntry",
            "when": "view == nodeDependencies && resourceFilename =~ /.*\\.xs\\.ts/",
            "group": "navigation"
        }
    ]
}

}
Although, a similar condition works for view/item/context and editor/title, it doesn't work for view/title. If I add another clause besides the one checking the view' name (view == nodeDependencies) the refresh button doesn't show up.

where are you getting this view context key from? see https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#visiblefocused-view-when-clause-context

@starball nodeDependencies is the name of the view defined in the sample, but that condition is not the problem, that works. The problem is that when you add any other clause like the one on my example it breaks

I tested it and I see you are right.
I would explain it by saying that the view/title's actions apply to the tree itself, not to individual resources.  You are refreshing the tree not a file.
Whereas, view/item/context and editor/title actions by their nature apply to individual resources and so resourceFileName makes sense there.
Apparently, the decision was made to ignore context keys like resourceFileName in the view/title bar because it's actions are applied at a higher level than resources like files.

Hi @Mark, thanks for your message. I thought the same as you, but I just wanted to be sure. Do you by any chance if could be possible to disable the view/title actions programatically? I already have some code to update the tree based on the active text editor.

You could use the setContext command in your extension and in the package.json.  Then you set that key true or false depending on some state you detect in your extension.  And that should toggle your view/title refresh icon.  See https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#add-a-custom-when-clause-context.  I can show an example from one of my extensions if you wish.

Thanks, @Mark. I did what you suggested and everything works as expected.
